# Why is Stack Overflow not displaying Markdown options in the answer section?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, markdown

I am not able to see the Stack Overflow Markdown options in the answer section, which contains options like **B** ***I***, attachment options, but the same is visible on Stack Exchange.

Is there a reason for that?

> [image]

Comment: anything blocked in your browser? Any errors in the dev console? Which browser / OS are you on?

Comment: Can you still not see it?

Comment: Shouldn't this go on Stack Overflow Meta? Unless this problem can be found in several places?